_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage18" doesn't exist
this works perfectly before but suddenly starts giving me this error on vscode. I have tried all the solutions i have seen online, but doesnt yet work, please who cn help
#create a class that holds the app most background frame. it contains nothing in itself except the #menu. But all other pages are called forward onto it

class SeaofBTCapp(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       
        #to add an icon image to the app has to be .ico file
        Tk.iconbitmap(self, default='C:/Users/aurel/Desktop/image.ico')

        #set title
        Tk.wm_title(self, 'InteL-Trader')
        self.state("zoomed") #window alway loads full

        global screen_height
        global screen_width
        global one_part
        global two_part

        screen_width=self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height=self.winfo_screenheight()

        #percentage unit of the screen width
        one_part=(16.36/100*screen_width)
    
        #percentage unit of the screen height
        two_part=10/100*screen_height
       
        #the is the whole app container untop of root screen(Self).
  
        Whole_App_Frame=Frame(self, width=screen_width, height=screen_height, bg='gold')
        Whole_App_Frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

        ################################################
            #Menus
        ################################################
        #create the menu container on the app background frame
       
        my_menu=Menu(Whole_App_Frame)

        #display the menu as your menu that tkinter should treat as such
        self.config(menu=my_menu)
        
        def Stop_bot(): #function to trigger the cloud code to stop
            pass

        file_menu=Menu(my_menu)
        my_menu.add_cascade(label="Home", menu=file_menu)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Home Page", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label="Log out MT5 Account", command=Stop_bot)
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=Whole_App_Frame.quit)
        
        #create menu option forAccount ####################################################################################################
        Account_menu=Menu(my_menu)
        my_menu.add_cascade(label="Account", menu=Account_menu)
        Account_menu.add_command(label="Account Data Page", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(AccountPage))
        Account_menu.add_separator()
        Account_menu.add_command(label="Receipts|Reports|Statements Downloads", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(DownloadsPage))

        #create menu option for Training ###################################################################################################
        Training_menu=Menu(my_menu)
        my_menu.add_cascade(label="Training", menu=Training_menu)
        Training_menu.add_command(label="How to use Intel Trader", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(HowtoIntel))
        Training_menu.add_separator()
        Training_menu.add_command(label="Forex basics", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ForexBasics))
        Training_menu.add_separator()
        Training_menu.add_command(label="Advanced Forex analysis and Strategies", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(AdvancedForex))

        #create menu option for Help #########################################################################################################
        help_menu=Menu(my_menu)
        my_menu.add_cascade(label="Help Centre", menu=help_menu)
        help_menu.add_command(label="Self Help Centre", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(CommunityHelpPage))
        help_menu.add_separator()
        help_menu.add_command(label="Contact US", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ContactsPage))
        help_menu.add_separator()
        help_menu.add_command(label="Direct Message and Calls", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(CallPage))

        #create menu option for Terms and Conditions without cascades and the function #############################################################
        my_menu.add_command(label="Terms and Conditions", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TermsPage))

        self.frames={} 
        #, DownloadsPage, HowtoIntel, ForexBasics, AdvancedForex, CommunityHelpPage, CallPage, ContactsPage, TermsPage,  PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree
        for F in (StartPage, AccountPage):    #this will contain all the pageframes and we can bring up any one at will with button calls
            frame=F(Whole_App_Frame, self)
            self.frames[F]=frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
        
        self.show_frame(StartPage) #start page is automatically loaded as the default page to be automatically displayed
        
    def show_frame(self, cont):  # this function searches the self.frames dictionary and moves up the page we want
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
##################################################################################################################################################################

##################################################################################################################################################################
#make startpage class 
class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parentclass, controller):
        
        Frame.__init__(self, parentclass)

        
        #################################create the first column frame using the percentage of total screen width and height######################################

        #logo and APP name frame##################################################################################
        Logo_screen_frame=LabelFrame(self, width=int(one_part), height=int(two_part), bg='green')
        Logo_screen_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=2, pady=0, sticky='n', columnspan=2, rowspan=1)
        
        #create a logo file in on the page of the app ############################################################
        logo=Image.open("C:/Users/aurel/trading app/logo1.PNG")
        logo=logo.resize((int(one_part/3), int(two_part-15)))
        ph=ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)
        label=Label(Logo_screen_frame, image=ph)
        label.image=ph
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ......

app=SeaofBTCapp()
app.geometry(str(screen_width)+'x'+str(screen_height))
ani=animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=1000)

app.mainloop()

File "c:\Users\aurel\trading app\freshtutorial.py", line 793, in <module>
    app=SeaofBTCapp()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\aurel\trading app\freshtutorial.py", line 205, in __init__
    frame=F(Whole_App_Frame, self)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\aurel\trading app\freshtutorial.py", line 234, in __init__
    label=Label(Logo_screen_frame, image=ph)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3237, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2648, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage18" doesn't exist
PS C:\Users\aurel\trading app>        
 

I was expecting to display image logo within a frame called logo_screen_frame but i got the error above. This same was working perfectly a few hours ago. Please if u have any idea where i gone wrong or what to fix, let me know. All codes are written in vscode

The error is mostly caused by multiple instances of Tk.  Also controller is undefined inside SeaofBTCapp.__init__().

Add mater=self inside the ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)

Work for me. I don't see no issue.

line 86, in init
for F in (StartPage, AccountPage):    #this will contain all the pageframes and we can bring up any one at will with button calls
NameError: name 'AccountPage' is not defined

hi toyota Supra, the AccountPage exists. i just didnt capture it in my post.  Also i found out that the animation function, is preventing my tkinter page from loading and functioning perfectly. My intention was to only use the animation function to update the live graph and not the whole page. Please how can i make the two processes run independently and simultaneously while they are still able to communicate?
